# How can I use big braces in an align* multi long equation in LaTeX?

Tags: equations, align

This is my code but it does not work when I change `\left(` and `\right)` to `\Big)` and `\Big)`

```
\begin{align*}
\bar{h}_{m}^{jk}&=\omega_{k}h_{m}^{jk}(a)\\
&=\left(  \omega_{k}\left\{
\zeta_{h}\mid\zeta_{h}\in p_{1}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\right\}  ,\omega
_{k}\left\{  \zeta_{h}\mid\zeta_{h}\in p_{2}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\right\}
,\dots, \right.\\
 &\qquad \left.\omega_{k}\left\{  \zeta_{h}\mid\zeta_{h}\in p_{m}\circ h_{m}%
^{jk}(a)\right\}  \right)  \\
&=\left(  \left\{  \bar{\zeta}_{h}\mid\bar{\ze
}_{h}\in p_{1}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\right\}  ,\left\{  \bar{\zeta}_{h}\mid
\bar{\zeta}_{h}\in p_{2}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\right\}  ,\dots,\left\{  \bar{\zeta
}_{h}\mid\bar{\zeta}_{h}\in p_{m}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\right\}  \right)  .
\end{align*}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `\left` is always paired with a `\right`, and this pairing cannot cross a `&` or `\\` .  Whoever wrote your code actually (correctly) paired `\left(` with `\right.` and `\left.` with `\right)`; the `.` means that TeX won't typeset the fence, but now knows how much to measure for the sizing.

Changing `\left(` to `\Big(` and `\right)` to `\Big)` means that you are leaving `\left.` and `\right.` in there, and TeX gets confused about what you're trying to pair.  The solution is that when you change `\left(` to `\Big(` and `\right)` to `\Big)` then you also need to remove the now superfluous `\left.` and `\right.`.

By the way, for spacing purposes, you may want to use `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)`.  That tells TeX that it is dealing with a left or right fence.

Comment: \Bigl( and \Bigr) can be used in align*, i change it in my code but it is not work

Comment: Did you also remove the `\left.` and `\right.`?  (Note the period hiding at the end of each.)

Comment: it is my mistake, i did not remove it, i still new in latex.. thank you:)

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\bar{h}_{m}^{jk}
    & = \omega_{k}h_{m}^{jk}(a)\\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
    \biggl(\omega_{k}\Bigl\{
        \zeta_{h}\mid\zeta_{h}\in p_{1}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\Bigr\},\omega_{k}
            \Bigl\{\zeta_{h}\mid\zeta_{h}\in p_{2}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)
                    \Bigr\}, \dots \\
    \dots, 
    \omega_{k}\Bigl\{\zeta_{h}\mid\zeta_{h}\in p_{m}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)
              \Bigr\}
    \biggr)
    \end{multlined} \\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t]
    \biggl(\Bigl\{\bar{\zeta}_{h}\mid\bar{\zeta}_{h}\in p_{1}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\Bigr\},
           \Bigl\{\bar{\zeta}_{h}\mid\bar{\zeta}_{h}\in p_{2}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)
           \Bigr\},\dots         \\
    \dots,
           \Bigl\{\bar{\zeta}_{h}\mid\bar{\zeta}_{h}\in p_{m}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\Bigr\}
    \biggr).
    \end{multlined}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]
(red lines shows text borders)

**Addendum:**
With use `aligned` instead of the `multilined` is possible to define anchors, where are aligned lines of multi line equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\bar{h}_{m}^{jk}
    & = \omega_{k}h_{m}^{jk}(a)\\
    & = \begin{aligned}[t]
        \biggl(\omega_{k}\Bigl\{
        \zeta_{h}\mid\zeta_{h}\in p_{1}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\Bigr\},
        &   \;\omega_{k}\Bigl\{\zeta_{h}\mid\zeta_{h}\in p_{2}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\Bigr\}, \dots \\
    \dots,
        &   \;\omega_{k}\Bigl\{\zeta_{h}\mid\zeta_{h}\in p_{m}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\Bigr\}\biggr)
        \end{aligned} \\
    & = \begin{aligned}[t]
        \biggl(\Bigl\{\bar{\zeta}_{h}\mid\bar{\zeta}_{h}\in p_{1}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\Bigr\},
        &\; \Bigl\{\bar{\zeta}_{h}\mid\bar{\zeta}_{h}\in p_{2}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\Bigr\},\dots \\
    \dots,
        &\; \Bigl\{\bar{\zeta}_{h}\mid\bar{\zeta}_{h}\in p_{m}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)\Bigr\}\biggr).
    \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can omega_{k} be under each other after split

Answer (score 0):

I propose this variant with a slightly simpler code, based on the  `fleqn` from `nccmath`, the `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` command  from `mathtools` and the `multlined` environment (same package).

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameColor}{\color{Coral}}
 \usepackage{nccmath, mathtools}
 \DeclarePairedDelimiter\set\{\}

\begin{document}
\leavevmode\vskip 1cm

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{align*}
\bar{h}_{m}^{jk} &=\omega_{k}h_{m}^{jk}(a) \\
&=\begin{multlined}[t][0.9\linewidth]\Bigl( \omega_{k}\set*{\zeta_{h}\mid\zeta_{h}\in p_{1}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)} ,\omega
_{k}\set{ \zeta_{h}\mid\zeta_{h}\in p_{2}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)},\dots \\[-1.5ex]
\dots, \omega_{k}\set*{ \zeta_{h}\mid\zeta_{h}\in p_{m}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)}\Bigr) \end{multlined} \\
&= \begin{multlined}[t][0.9\linewidth]\Bigl( \set*{ \bar{\zeta}_{h}\mid\bar{\zeta}_{h}\in p_{1}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)} ,%
\set*{ \bar{\zeta}_{h}\mid \bar{\zeta}_{h}\in p_{2}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)} ,\dots \phantom{.} \\[-1.5ex]
\dots, \set*{ \bar{\zeta}_{h}\mid\bar{\zeta}_{h}\in p_{m}\circ h_{m}^{jk}(a)} \Bigr).
\end{multlined}
\end{align*}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]